# Tieferes Verständnis von "jeder" und "alle"

Tags: numbers, semantics

Das Wort "alle" wird verwendet für Pluraliatantum und Singulariatantum:

> Alles Salz, alle Liebe, aller Pfeffer, alle Leute

Es wird ebenfalls verwendet für zählbare Substantive im Plural. Für zählbare Adjektive im Singular wird zudem noch "jeder" verwendet:

> Jeder Mensch, jede Pfeffersorte, jedes Tier, jedes Kind

Gibt es eine tiefergehende semantische Bedeutung dieser Art der Verwendung? Mir erscheint dies als sprachliche Irregularität. Weiß jemand, wie die Verwendung von "jeder" und "alle" in anderen (nicht-indoeuropäischen) Sprachen gehandhabt wird?

Comment: Actually, it is funny that the answer to this question leads me to further questions: in mathematics, we use 'for all x ...' as an expression. It actually means 'for every x' but it becomes ambiguous at some places. Thank God the difference exists here, because in mathematical symbols, as fas as I know, it doesn't. Help!

Comment: English has pretty much the same distinction between "all" and "each".

Comment: Kürzlich hörte ich "Jeder erwachsene Deutsche kann der nächste Bundeskanzler werden, aber nicht alle." Ein einleuchtendes Beispiel, aber ich bezweifle ein wenig, dass diese Unterscheidung den meisten bewusst ist. Daher würde ich mich beim Lesen u. Hören nicht darauf verlassen, beim Sprechen u. Schreiben aber bemühen dies so zu handhaben.

Comment: "Zählbare Adjektive"? Wie darf man sich das denn vorstellen? "Ein gut, zwei guts" - oder "zwei gutes"? Und wenn man dann jeder verwendet, steht das Adjektiv wieder im Singular: "Ein grün, zwei güns, drei grüns. Das sind dann alle grün!"

Answer (score 7):

Das Zahlwort *alle* fasst eine Gruppe zusammen und im Folgenden werden die Individuen dieser Gruppe nicht mehr unterschieden. Es wird nachdrücklich darauf hingewiesen, dass es sich um sämtliche "Objekte" eines Typen handelt. Ohne Ausnahme. Nicht eines, nicht zwei, sondern *alle*.
Trotz der implizierten Gruppierung verwendest du das Nomen im Plural, sofern es einen gibt.

Eine Gruppierung findet auch beim Gebrauch des Zahlwortes *jeder* statt. Auch hier: ohne Ausnahme. Trotzdem betrachtest du im Nachhinein jedes Individuum einzeln. Du iterierst über die Objekte und wendest die Satzaussage auf jedes Objekt einzeln an.
Und hier kommt der grammatikalische Unterschied zum Tragen: Das Nomen steht im Singular.

Als Beispiel betrachte doch einfach die folgende Aussage (auch wenn man an der Korrektheit zweifeln darf):

> Alle Menschen sind gleich. Sie sehnen sich nach Erfolg. Und doch geht jeder Mensch seinen eigenen Weg.

Comment: Alle Berge, höher als 8820 m, können auch ein oder zwei sein. Nach dramatischen Erdrutschen sogar keiner. Alle kann nicht alle außer ein oder zwei sein.

Comment: @userunknown Manchmal habe ich das Gefühl, du verstehst Dinge mit Absicht falsch. Nirgends, aber auch nirgends, habe ich geschrieben, dass alle ungleich ein bzw. zwei sei. (Und doch, ich weiß, über welche Stelle im Text du 'gestolpert' bist. Aber wie gesagt, ich erahne da absichtliches Missverstehen.)

Comment: Ich habs einfach gelesen und mir gedacht, dass das ein Widerspruch ist, weil es Mengen gibt, die weniger als 3 Elemente haben. Wenn Du schreibst "Nicht eins, nicht zwei, sondern alle" schließt Du das aus. Daran ändert auch ein Dementi nichts - es steht ja da.

Answer (score 2):

Mir scheint die Differenzierung zwischen "alle" und "jeder" eine graduelle Verschiebung des Fokus zu sein.

"Ich mag alle Menschen": Ich mag die Menschen in ihrer Gesamtheit, also individuell undifferenziert.

"Ich mag jeden Menschen": Ich mag jeden einzeln, für sich, wodurch eine Gesamtheit die *Folge* ist. Hier wird individuell differenziert argumentiert.

Bezeichnend und meine Argumentation unterstützend, ist an diesem Beispiel der Umstand, dass sich das homonyme Wort "Menschen" vom Plural im ersten zum Singular im zweiten Satz wandelt.

Comment: Aber "Ich mag alle Menschen" ist bei weitem nicht dasselbe wie "Ich mag die Menschheit"! Auch empfinde ich nicht, dass "Alle Menschen sind sterblich" so etwas wie "Die Menschheit stirbt aus" implizieren würde. Insofern sehe ich alle/jeder als - normalerweise - weitgehend bedeutungsgleich an. Andererseits kann jedoch in der Tat "Alle Menschen werden Brüder" nicht zu "Jeder Mensch wird ein Bruder" umformuliert werden; auch besagt "All deine Meckereien gehen mir auf den Keks" in der Tat nicht, dass diese im Einzelfall stören, sondern als Gesamtheit (aufgrund ihrer Anzahl).

Comment: Ich bestreite, dass man alle Menschen oder jeden Menschen mögen kann, weswegen das Beispiel wertlos ist. "Jeder Schüler kann Klassensprecher werden, aber nicht alle" wäre ein besseres Beispiel.

Answer (score 1):

Zum Thema nicht-indoeuropäische Sprachen kann ich nur sagen, dass im Japanischen und im Chinesischen die Unterscheidung zwischen zählbar und unzählbar gar nicht existiert.

Dort sind alle Substantive unzählbar und deshalb wird ein Klassifizierungswort benötigt, etwa wie bei "eine **Tasse** Tee" oder "ein **Stück** Holz". Je nach Form oder Typ des Objekts wird ein anderes Wort gebraucht.

Answer (score 0):

Aus meiner Auffassung vom Sprachgebrauch stimme ich zu:

"Alle" betrachtet alle Elemente der Gruppe zusammengefasst als ein Ganzes. "Jeder" betrachtet die Elemente jeweils einzeln. Das hat auch praktische Relevanz. Beispiel:

Der Kirchengemeinderat entscheidet über die Gestaltung aller Gottesdienste, der Pfarrer entscheidet über die Gestaltung jedes Gottesdienstes. Hier fasst der Kirchengemeinderat einen Beschluss z.B. über die Gottesdienstordnung als allgemeine Regelung. Der Pfarrer entscheidet jedes Mal im Einzelfall über die konkrete Gestaltung des jeweiligen Gottesdienstes.

Comment: Kannst Du vielleicht auch etwas zu den Fragen schreiben, die shuhalo im letzten Absatz stellt?

Answer (score 0):

"All": Curiously intertwined with "One", and "Each". This is a bottomless topic! There is a classic (German) work in philosophy that delves into such matters: Die Grundlagen der Arithmetik, by Gottlob Frege, 1884, which I read in German long ago. It would be impossible to go into the work in full depth (or, unfortunately, for me to write my answer in good German!), but, to give a flavor of the analysis, here is an excerpt (p. 30) about agglomeration:

...denn es giebt sehr verschiedene Weisen, wie man ein Aggregat zerlegen kann, und man kann nicht sagen, dass Eine allein charakteristisch Wäre. Ein Bündel Stroh kann z. B. so zerlegt werden, dass man alle halme durchschneidet, oder so, dass man es in einzelne Halme auflöst, oder so dass man zwei Bündel daraus macht. Ist denn ein Haufe von hundert Sandkörner ebenso zusammengesetzt wie ein Bündel von 100 Strohhalmen? und doch hat man dieselbe Zahl. Das Zahlwort "Ein" in dem Ausdruck "Ein Strohhalm" drückt doch nicht aus, wie dieser Halm aus Zellen oder aus Molekeln zusammengesetzt ist. Noch mehr Schwierigkeit macht die Zahl 0. Müssen denn die Strohhalme überhaupt ein Bündel bilden, um gezählt werden zu können? Muss man die Blinden im Deutschen Reiche durchaus in einer Versammlung vereinigen, damit der Ausdruck "Zahl der Blinden im Deutschen Reiche" einen Sinn habe? Sind tausend Weizenkörner, nachdem sie ausgesäet sind, nicht mehr tausend Weizenkörner? Giebt es eigentlich Aggregate von Beweisen eines Lehrsatzes oder von Ereignissen? und doch kann man auch diese zählen. Dabei is es gleichgiltig, ob die Ereignisse gleichzeitig oder durch Jahrtausende getrennt sind.

For another viewpoint, "All" is mathematically something like "unity". "All horses" times 2 just gives you "All horses" back again (1*2 = 2).

One of my favorite quotes, because of its many ramifications, is Euclid's definition of unity: "A unit is that by virtue of which each thing that exists is called one". The more I think about it, the more it captures the many different facets of "one" -- as well as "all".